# Should the member of class be a pointer?

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers

I'm a bit confused. If you search about the usefulness of (smart) pointers you get very different opinions. 
Almost everybody agrees that one should use smart pointers over normal pointers, but there are also many opinions that you should not use pointers at all in modern C++.

Lets consider this abstract situation (Which is similar to my problem): 
You have one class "Clothes" which has a member of type "Hat"

```
class Hat {
public:
    enum class HatType{
        sombrero,
        sun hat,
        helmet,
        beanie,
        cowboy_hat
    };
    // some functions
private:
    HatType type;
    // some members
}

class Clothes {
public:
    // some functions
private:
    Hat currentHat;
    // some other members of other types
}
```

Is there any Difference in run time if I would change `Hat` to `Hat*` (or a `unique_ptr<Hat>`?). 
(In many functions of `Clothes` you would need to call something from `Hat`)

The reason I ask is because there are many different types of hats.
Like sombreros, sun hats, helmets, beanies and cowboy hats. Right now my class hat has an enumerator which stores the hat type.
The hat type is only relevant in one specific function of `Hat` but this is the most used function.

Right now I use a simple `switch case` in this specific function and based on the hat type the function is evaluated a bit differently. This worked fine but I think it would be smarter to simply make an own class for every different hat type which inherit from one single main `Hat` class and override the one function.

To do so I think I would have to change the member `currentHat` in `Clothes` to any type of pointer. I researched if this would have any negative effects on my performance (I thought about maybe because the location of my `currentHat` object and my `Clothes` object in memory can be wide apart, but I have no Idea if this would happen and if this would have any negative effects with modern compilers).

During my research I often read that one should avoid pointers, this made me thinking... some of the information I found was also very old and I do not know if this is outdated. Is there any better way to do this?

Has anyone any experience with this kind of problem? Would be good to get some feedback before I spend a lot of time changing my whole project...

Side note: I took `Clothes` and `Hats` only as an examples. In my real application I have different types and I am creating many million of objects from type `Clothes` and I have to call functions of `Clothes` which will call functions of `Hat` many many million times, that is why I'm concerned with run time.

Edit: Maybe it is also worth noting that I have entirely avoided pointers in my application so far, mostly because I read in some books that one should try to avoid pointers :-)

EDIT2: Thank you for all your answers. Please note that part of my question was not how to do it (although the answers were very useful in that depart) but rather if the performance will suffer from this.

Comment: How can you not use pointers at all? This would probably kill polymorphism dead

Comment: Wrong abstraction. A `Hat` is-a `Clothes` (er, that's a poor class name, for there being no singular). This should be modeled using derivation. On the question of pointers: They have their uses. They can be used to describe, that there are either 0 or 1 instances. They can be used to model shared ownership. And probably a number of other use cases, too.

Comment: In your case `std::variant` might be better.

Comment: I'm not a professional programmer. I use it to do my science. Therefore I have not used polymorphismn before... but I think it would be a good idea to start using this handy tools

Comment: @KillzoneKid: Polymorphism is available through references just as well. You don't *need* pointers to have polymorphism.

Comment: @KillzoneKid: There are a lot more solutions for polymorphic behaviour. One of them is using std::variant. You can also handcraft function dispatching in any kind you like. Using virtual methods/vtable dispatching is one of the c++ internal features but not the only one!

Comment: @IInspectable Obviously, but would not using pointers make it awkward and complicated?

Comment: @Klaus Am still on C++14. Will cross that bridge when I get there ;)

Comment: @KillzoneKid: Would it? How so, exactly? Does `void foo(base const&)` look *that* awkward? A matter of taste, to some degree. Either way, this doesn't right your initial statement. Which just so happens to be wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable Can't help but think of immediate disadvantages of references vs pointers and how this might complicate things

Comment: @KillzoneKid: What *"immediate disadvantages"*? How does it *"complicate things"*? Just voicing opinion, without providing rationale, or even just an example isn't very helpful.

Comment: @KillzoneKid: No need for c++14. You can also use boost for this.

Comment: You always need to think at least a little bit about the rule-of-three and rule-of-five.  When you use Hat* then you *must* think about it, copying pointers does not often come to a good end.  That doesn't have to be a big deal, copying somebody's clothes doesn't often make much sense.  But make it explicit with =delete so you don't have to worry about accidents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, let's break down the pointer debacle:

### Don't use explicit `new`/`delete` in C++

There really isn't any exception to this rule. Except if you are writing a library/framework. Or some fancy stuff that requires placement new. But in user code `new`/`delete` should be 100% absent.

This brings us to my next rule:

### Don't use raw pointers to denote ownership.

This you will find often on the net as the "Don't use raw pointers" advice/rule. But in my view the problem is not with raw pointers, but with raw pointers that own an object.

For ownership use smart pointers (`unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`). If a pointer is not an owner of the object then it's ok if you use raw pointers. For instance in a tree like structure you can have `unique_ptr` to the children and a raw pointer to the parent.

You can (arguably) also use a pointer to denote an *optional* value via `nullptr`.

### You need to use pointers or references for dynamic polymorphism

(Well... there are other ways, like type erasure but I won't go there in my post) If you want polymorphism then you can't use a value. If you can use reference then do, but most of the time you can't. Which often means you have to use `unique_ptr`.

Comment: i cant help myself but if i see a typo i have to fix it ;)

Comment: @user463035818 that's ok. I actually am grateful

Comment: I would add that there is optional to denote an ... optional value :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a breakdown of your three suggested implementations, and some more:

#### Plain member: `Hat currentHat;`

- `Clothes` uniquely owns the `Hat`
- No dynamic allocation
- No polymorphism

#### Smart pointer: `std::unique_ptr<Hat> currentHat;`

- `Clothes` still uniquely owns the `Hat`
- Dynamic allocation required
- Polymorphism available, i.e. can hold instances derived from `Hat`

#### Raw pointer: `Hat *currentHat;`

- `Clothes` does not own the `Hat`
- Unspecified allocation, need to ensure that the `Hat` outlives the `Clothes`
- Polymorphism still available
- Perfectly fine if these are your requirements. Fight me :)

---

### Unlisted contenders

#### Smart pointer: `std::shared_ptr<Hat> currentHat;`

- `Clothes` shares ownership of the `Hat` with zero or more other `Clothes`
- Same as `std::unique_ptr` otherwise

#### Reference: `Hat &currentHat;`

- Similar to a raw pointer
- Is non-rebindable, thus makes the object non-assignable -- hence I don't personally like member references in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

As you need *different* Heads, you have basically two options:

1) Using a (smart) pointer, this is well known and easy

2) Using std::variant

This is a vary different approach! No longer need of a base class and ( pure ) virtual methods. Instead of this using the `std::visit` to access the current object in the *tagged union*. But this comes with a cost: Dispatching in std::visit can be expensive if the compiler did not hardly optimize the call table inside. But if it can, it is simply taking the tag from the variant and use it as a index to the overloaded function from your visit call, here given as a generic lambda. That is not as fast as indirect call via vtable pointer, but not more than a view instructions more ( if it is optimized!).

As always: How you want t go is a matter of taste.

Example:

```
class Head1
{
    public:
        void Print() { std::cout << "Head1" << std::endl; }
};

class Head2
{
    public:
        void Print() { std::cout << "Head2" << std::endl; }
};

class Clothes
{
    std::variant<Head1,Head2> currentHead;

    public:

    Clothes()
    {
        currentHead = Head1();
    }

    void Do() { std::visit( [](auto& head){ head.Print();}, currentHead); }

    void SetHead( int id )
    {
        switch( id )
        {
            case 0:
                currentHead= Head1();
                break;
            case 1:
                currentHead= Head2();
                break;

            default:
                std::cerr << "Wrong id for SetHead" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    Clothes cl;
    cl.Do();
    cl.SetHead(1);
    cl.Do();
    cl.SetHead(0);
    cl.Do();
}
```